# How to use ngx-bootstrap in stackblitz.com without use a <link href> to import bs css?

Tags: angular, bootstrap-4, ngx-bootstrap, stackblitz

Here is my stackblitz.com demo :
https://stackblitz.com/edit/ngx-bs-test

and I need to add `<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">` to every html file witch I used .

I have done every thing that official document said, install dependencies , add `"node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css",` to angular.json 
. but the style just not displayed.

can any one tell me the right way to use ngx-bootstrap style in stackblitz?

Comment: if you want to import normal bootstrap then import css to you root style sheet (style.css) using `@import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';` instead of adding to angular.json after `npm i bootstrap`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can follow Official docs and add bootstrap into `angular.json` like that

```
"styles": [
    "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css",
    "src/styles.css"
],
```

https://stackblitz.com/edit/ngx-bs-test-mc1rqy?file=angular.json

Comment: well, after comparison the code between yours and mine line by line I fount I just have a extra comma after` "src/styles.css"` , that's too stupid...

Comment: yep, this small mistakes are creates huge problem and waste much time :D

Answer (score 0):

you can just update your index.html like so:

```
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" 
rel="stylesheet">

<my-app>loading</my-app>
```

Greetings

Answer (score 0):

`npm i bootstrap` and then you edit angular.json file

```
"architect": {
  "build": {
     "options": {
         "styles": [
              "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css",
              "src/styles.scss",
          ],
     }  
  }
}
```